# Scripting - if grep "Used : X GB" > Y then

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting

I have scoured the internet for a way to query an ESXi hosts used RAM, and I found one which even included the Used Mhz to boot, in a nice output. My real end goal is to get an XYMon script to monitor the output. I can make the XYMon script, but I have no idea how to get the `IF THEN` statement to work.

Here is the output of my query :

```
[Host] Name                    : esxi.domain.com
[Host] CPU Detail              : Processor Sockets: 1, Cores per Socket 4
[Host] CPU Type                : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz
[Host] CPU Usage               : Used: 836 Mhz, Total: 16028 Mhz
[Host] Memory Usage            : Used: 59 GB, Total: 64 GB
```

I need an `IF THAN` statement that basically says **IF (Used # of RAM) is greater than (Y), THEN.**

If it's possible to make the script portable, I would like there to be an **IF (Used # of RAM) > (%Total of RAM) THEN**. This way I can publish the script and people can use it without modifying the `Y` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#/bin/bash

memory=$(grep "Memory Usage" /tmp/esxihealth | grep -o '[0-9]*' | tr '\n' ' ')
ramused=$(echo $memory | cut -d' ' -f1)
ramtotal=$(echo $memory | cut -d' ' -f2)
rampercent=$((200*$ramused/$ramtotal % 2 + 100*$ramused/$ramtotal))
ramthreshold=95

if (( rampercent > ramthreshold )); then
        ramhigh=true
fi

cpu=$(grep "CPU Usage" /tmp/esxihealth | grep -o '[0-9]*' | tr '\n' ' ')
cpuused=$(echo $cpu | cut -d' ' -f1)
cputotal=$(echo $cpu | cut -d' ' -f2)
cpupercent=$((200*$cpuused/$cputotal % 2 + 100*$cpuused/$cputotal))
cputhreshold=90

if (( cpupercent > cputhreshold )); then
       cpuhigh=true
fi

if [ ! -z "$ramhigh" ] || [ ! -z "$cpuhigh" ]; then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

percentage can be found this way:

```
CMD > /tmp/esxihealth
percent=$(awk '/Memory Usage/ { printf "%d\n",100*$6/$9+.5 ;}' /tmp/esxihealth)
```

no need for so many pipes.

in awk `$6` will pick the 6-th field (by default field are separated by one or more space or tab).

Comment: By my count it's `$5` and `$8`. And the self-answer now indicates they want a rounded value, so `100*$5/$8+.5`

Comment: found 6 and 9, anyway this is not that hard to change.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the greatest `bash` scripter, so someone might have a more elegant solution, but the solution below works. Your `Y` variable is the `threshold` variable in the script, and the name of the file that contains the data you have given is called `memstats`:

```
#!/bin/bash

memory=$(grep "Memory Usage" memstats | grep -o '[0-9]*' | tr '\n' ' ')
used=$(echo $memory | cut -d' ' -f1)
total=$(echo $memory | cut -d' ' -f2)


threshhold=50

if (($used > $threshhold)); then
        echo "do this (used is greater than threshold)"
else
        echo "do this else (used is less than threshold)"
fi
```

Comment: Here is the final Product if you wana see :), thanks again! https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/index.php/2016/09/16/xymon-esxi-ramcpu-monitor-script-no-vclivma/